# TeamCity skips internal publishing after Artifactory plugin publishing error

Tags: teamcity, artifactory

We recently added a build step in each of our TeamCity build configurations which will publish certain artifacts to Artifactory (in addition to TeamCity publishing internally). We are working through some issues with our Artifactory repo preventing us from adding new files. When this happens, the Artifactory plugin in TeamCity errors out and the last step of publishing artifacts into other TeamCity locations also fails.

Is there a way to continue publishing artifacts in TeamCity even if the Artifactory publishing fails?

```
Step 2/2: Publish to Artifactory (Command Line)
    [Step 2/2] Error deploying artifact: 
    Skipping deployment of remaining artifacts (if any) and build info.
Build was interrupted. Artifacts will not be published for this build
```

Comment: Do you know what cause the artifacts publishing to fail? Is this a specific file that fails to be published? Is this failure consistent or random? Did you look at the Artifactory logs for some clues?

Comment: Our server is full and we are adding more storage. Some smaller files do publish to Artifactory as expected. I am trying to make sure that even if the push to Artifactory fails for some reason that the TeamCity internal publishing will continue.

Comment: I understand the scenario now. Thanks. Currently there's no way to have the build ignore or skip Artifactory deployment failures.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

There's no way since your step is failing.

In order to not have your builds brake you can create another build configuration in the same build chain to publish to Artifactory. This new build configuration will publish the artifacts generated in the previous build, if it fails you can easily run it again.

[image]